# Create an object called Accounts to be used for banking

Tags: python

> 1. Create an object called Accounts. This is to be used in a banking system.
> 2. Initialize the account with three data as inputs : Firstname, Lastname and initial deposit.
> 3. Create 4 additional member functions: Deposit, Withdraw, Fee Calculations, interest
>    The fee calculation is going to be $10 per month if the total amount in the account is less than $1000. Interest is set to be at 3%.

I already got the code to work once, however it was with all the variables as integers, meaning none of them were decimals. Here's what I have now and I keep getting errors:

```
input = 'John Doe 4893.27'

account = str(input)
account = account.split()

first_name = account[0]
last_name = account[1]
i_deposit = account[2]

i_deposit = float(i_deposit)
i_deposit = '{:.2f}'.format(i_deposit)

new_amount = 0
fee = 0
d = 0
w = 0


def Deposit(d):
    d = float(d)
    d = '{:.2f}'.format(d)
    d = bin(d)
    new_amount = bin(i_deposit) + d
    new_amount =  bin(new_amount)
    return bin(new_amount)


def Withdraw(w):
    w = float(w)
    w = '{:.2f}'.format(d)
    w = bin(w)
    new_amount = bin(i_deposit) + w
    new_amount = bin(new_amount)
    return bin(new_amount)


def FeeCalc(money):
    money = float(i_deposit)
    if money <= 1000:
        fee = 10
    else:
        fee = 0
    fee = '{:.2f}'.format(fee)
    return fee

i = 0
def Interest(i):
    i = float(i_deposit)
    i = int(i)
    i = i * .03
    i = '{:.2f}'.format(i)
    return i

dep_amount = Deposit(d)
wit_amount = Withdraw(w)
net_amount =  sum(dep_amount, wit_amount)
new_amount = int(new_amount)
int_fee = Interest(i)

Withdraw(276.84)

print(first_name, last_name, 'account information:', '\nInitial deposit: $', i_deposit, '\nNew balance: $', new_amount, '\nFee: $', fee, '\nInterest: $', int_fee)
```

The most recent error I can't seem to fix:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shardae/PycharmProjects/HW1/main.py", line 55, in <module>
    dep_amount = Deposit(d)
  File "/Users/shardae/PycharmProjects/HW1/main.py", line 23, in Deposit
    d = bin(d)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please add the error and traceback to the question.

Comment: Also, I wanted to point out (though not an error of code) but it says you need to create an object which would mean a class in Python.

Comment: I have added the traceback error.

Comment: Using the format string makes it into not a floating point number. Although if you're dealing with limited decimal precision, then just store everything as an integer in terms of base units (eg `123` units is `$1.23`) so you can avoid all the roundoff and floating point math things.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "'{:.2f}'.format(some_variable)" function, you are actually converting whatever variable you are assigning a value into a string.  I don't believe that is what you after.  With that, let me offer up some revision to your program that keeps the spirit of your code.

```
input = 'John Doe 4893.27'

account = str(input)
account = account.split()

first_name = account[0]
last_name = account[1]
i_deposit = float(account[2])

def Deposit(amount, d):
    amount = amount + d
    return amount

def Withdraw(amount, w):
    w = (int(w) * 100) / 100    # Example of insuring precision to two decimal places
    amount = amount - w
    return amount

def FeeCalc(money):
    fee = 0
    if money <= 1000.00:
        fee = 10
    return fee

def Interest():
    i = float(i_deposit)
    i = int(i)
    i = i * .03
    return i

new_amount = i_deposit              # Set the work field to the initial deposit balance

int_fee = Interest()                # Calculate interest and add it to the balance

new_amount += int_fee               

new_amount = Withdraw(new_amount, 276.84)   # Calculate the new balance once the withdrawal amount is applied

fee = FeeCalc(new_amount)               # Subtract any bank fee if the balance has dropped below $1000.00

new_amount -= fee

print(first_name, last_name, 'account information:', '\nInitial deposit: $', '{:.2f}'.format(i_deposit), '\nNew balance: $', '{:.2f}'.format(new_amount), '\nFee: $', fee, '\nInterest: $', int_fee)
```

The code still does utilize floating point variables.  However, the only time that specific formatting for two decimal points occurs is within the printed output.

Go ahead and review the tweaks and see if that fulfills the spirit of your solution.

Hope that helps.

Regards.